# Xen Kernel - SCSI_WAIT_SCAN Module

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, xen

We've recently deployed a HP ProLiant DL180 Gen9 with 12 x Intel 530 SSD Drives. The system is running RAID-10 on top of HP Smart Array P840.

Our aim was to use Xen on this server. However, when the kernel supplied by CentOS was installed, we noticed that the server does not boot and gives kernel panic (screenshot below).

I have tried to search for module SCSI_WAIT_SCAN, however could not find much information about this - for kernel v3.10. What exactly this error tells us?

[image: Screenshot of kernel panic.]

Comment: I think kernel panic has nothing with missing module. Check this [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60758) and in the bottom there is a workaround  because dracut does not match symbol blk_mq_init_queue. Hope it helps.